# Can't read data from settings.ini file

Tags: python, config, ini

I'm using `configparser` and I can't get data from my `settings.ini` file. When I try, this error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\Desktop\a=''.py", line 44, in <module>
    if config['settings']['x']== 'Yes':
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 1257, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'x'
```

If I try `config['settings']['x'] = input('x')` on the same run of the code with it, I don't get an error. Yes, it's in the same directory and data can be written to it with the code above. When I print `config.sections()`, settings are printed. I also tried to print all the keys in `config['settings']` but it ran without error and without output.

Here's the minimal reproducible code for reading in the settings file:

```
import configparser 
config=configparser.ConfigParser() 
def settings(): 
    config['settings']={} 
    config['settings']['x']=input('x') 
    with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile: 
        config.write(configfile) #error if i dont run this 
        print(config.sections()) 
        print('x' in config['settings']) #error here 
        for key in config['settings']:
            print(key) 
            with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
                config.write(configfile)
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\x\Desktop\test.py", line 10, in <module>
     print('x' in config['settings'])
   File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 963, in __getitem__
     raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'settings'
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example code?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well first, you have two context managers (`with` statement), one within another.